# How Can I distinguish user is login from Web or Android or IOS?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

I Am using AIR 14 and flash cs6 and actionscript3.I developed one game.now i want to play that game in web,android,ios.But the problem is whenever user login i want to know from where he/she login means (web,android,ios).How can i know.any suggestion.

Comment: You have to publish a different files for android, ios and web.  So you don't need to detect those, you can just code it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`flash.system.Capablities`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) has an [`os`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os) property that will give you a string representation of the operating system the user has.

Comment: But for android device am getting os as Linux.but desktop system also having os linux.now how can i distinguish these two.@cyangel

Comment: Unfortunately Android is a Linux OS so we cant use the OS property to differentiate those two. You could however use [`Mouse.supportsCursor`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html#supportsCursor) to help there

Comment: Thank you for your reply.but how can i use Mouse.supportsCursor.can you explain me briefly.@cyangel

Comment: Computers "usually have" cursors, mobiles don't

Comment: Got it.for desktop game Mouse.supportsCursor is true.and for mobiles it is false.